# ¿Como imprimir caracteres unicode dinamicamente?

Tags: c++, unicode

tengo una duda, estoy escribiendo un programa en `c++`, en el cual necesito escribir caracteres unicode, pero de manera dinámica.

Por ejemplo, con el siguiente código, escribo un archivo de texto con caracteres unicode:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){
    std::string texto = "Texto con caracteres unicode \u0305";
    std::ofstream salida("./archivo_de_salida.txt");
    if(salida.is_open()){
        //Escribo los datos
        salida << texto;
    }
    salida.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Pero... ¿Como puedo escribir caracteres unicode de manera dinámica?
Por ejemplo:

```
std::string code = "0305";
std::string caracter_unicode = "\u" + code;
```

¿Es eso posible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un carácter Unicode, además de formar parte de un string estático (para lo que has de usar `\u` dentro de la cadena y no se puede generar de forma dinámica), también puede almacenarse individualmente en una variable de tipo `wchar_t` (aunque esto no es muy portable pues el tamaño de este tipo depende del compilador).

En este caso sí puedes asignar a tu variable de tipo `wchar_t` un valor numérico cualquiera en tiempo de ejecución. El problema es que a la hora de volcar esa variable a un fichero (o a la salida estándar) tienes que:

- Usar cadenas "anchas", (`wstring`). En las literales eso implica poner una `L` delante de las comillas de apertura.
- Usar *streams* que admitan ese tipo. Lo que significa cambiar `std::ofstream` por `std::wofstream`, o `std::out` por `std::wout`, etc.
- Elegir un *encoding* correcto para ese *stream*, lo cual puedes hacerlo a través del *locale*.

Una prueba de concepto:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
  std::wofstream salida("./archivo_de_salida.txt");

  // Poner el encoding según el locale
  std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
  salida.imbue(std::locale());

  if(salida.is_open()){
        //Escribo los datos
        salida << L"Texto con caracteres unicode \u0305\n";
        salida << L"Texto con caracteres unicode " << (wchar_t)0x305 << L"\n";
    }
  salida.close();
}
```

En el fichero aparece:

```
Texto con caracteres unicode ̅
Texto con caracteres unicode ̅
```

Observa que la constante de tipo `wchar_t` se especifica en realidad como un entero (he usado `0x0305` para que, gracias al prefijo `0x`, pueda verse su valor hexadecimal, pero lo mismo podría haber puesto su valor decimal que es `773`). No es una cadena. Si necesitas tenerlo en una cadena como en tu ejemplo (`"0305"`), puedes convertir esta cadena en entero usando `strtoul()`.

Prueba de concepto:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
  std::string code = "0305";

  std::wofstream salida("./archivo_de_salida.txt");

  // Poner el encoding según el locale
  std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
  salida.imbue(std::locale());

  if(salida.is_open()){
        //Escribo los datos
        salida << L"Texto con caracteres unicode " << (wchar_t)strtoul(code.c_str(), NULL, 16) << L"\n";
    }
  salida.close();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No es lo mismo una [secuencia de escape](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) que una secuencia de caracteres.

Para entender la diferencia, debemos comprender las [fases de traducción](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) de un programa C++:

1. **Cada carácter del código fuente se mapea a los caracteres del conjunto básico**, los caracteres que no pueden ser mapeados se reemplazan por secuencias de escape.
2. El código separado en múltiples líneas por una barra descendente (`\`) se junta en una sola línea.
3. Se clasifica el contenido del código en comentarios, espacios y directivas de pre-procesador.
4. Se ejecuta el pre-procesador, las inclusiones (`#include`) se añaden al archivo haciéndolas pasar por las fases 1 a 4 recursivamente, después de esta fase no quedan directivas de pre-procesador en el archivo.
5. **Los literales de texto (caracteres y cadenas) se convierten del conjunto básico al conjunto de ejecución**, incluidas las secuencias de escape.
6. Se concatenan los literales de texto adyacentes.
7. Se compila el código en unidades de traducción.
8. Se instancian las plantillas que cada unidad de traducción requiere.
9. Se enlazan las unidades de traducción.

Por lo tanto, si tienes este código:

```
std::cout << "̅  Hola Mundo ̅ \n";
```

En la primera fase se transformará en:

```
std::cout << "\u0305 Hola Mundo \u0305\n";
```

Y en la quinta será:

```
std::cout << "̅  Hola Mundo ̅ 
";
```

Fíjate que el salto de línea (`\n`) ahora es explícito en lugar de una secuencia de escape. Pero si tienes el siguiente código:

```
std::string code = "0305";
std::string caracter_unicode = "\u" + code;
std::cout << caracter_unicode;
```

En la primera fase queda inalterado (todos los caracteres pertenecen al conjunto básico) pero en la quinta quedará así:

```
std::string code = "0305";
std::string caracter_unicode = "u" + code;
std::cout << caracter_unicode;
```

Fíjate que la secuencia `\u` queda como `u`.

> ¿Como puedo escribir caracteres unicode de manera dinámica?

No se puede escribir Unicode de manera dinámica, los caracteres son traducidos **antes** (fase 5) de compilar (fase 7).

Comment: ¿No existe alguna función que sea similar a "fromCodePoint" de `javascript`?